# System.Diagnostic.Process.Start not working

Tags: .net

I have this code

```
                Process P = new Process();
                P.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                P.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                P.StartInfo.FileName = 11.avi;
                P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

                P.Start();
                P.WaitForExit();
                P.Dispose();
```

When I run it Windows Media Player launches and plays the avi file. So far so good, however when teh WaitForExit is called I get an exception 
"No process is associated with this object".
What am I doing wrong, setting ShellExcecute to false does not help either. What is really weird is if I use an mkv file VLC player launches and this code works fine. What is so special about .avi files ( the file extension I mean obviously the file type is not important here )
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about an AVI. Media Player spawns a process and exits when launched from the command line. Because of that there is nothing to wait for. VLC player probably doesn't do this.

You can verify this by opening a command prompt and launching each type of file to see the behavior.

Consider using the method of using Media Player outlined in [Embedding the Windows Media Player Control in a C# Solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you have set [UseShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx) to true, it's actually the operating system shell that starts the process. If you look at the parent process of your launched wmplayer instance, you'll see it's actually not your process that started it (just tested it, in my case it's a `svchost.exe` instance), thus your `Process` instance is not associated with an actual process. What starts your process depends on how the shell handles your file extension, so `avi` matters here.

Note that in your case `P.Start();` returns `false`.

Comment: well I tried it shellexec to false and same problem.Any Ideas on how I can get this to work. I guess I could run wmplayer with the file name as an argument?